# Flask is not providing a URL

Tags: python, flask, discord, bots

I am a new programmer and I am trying to connect my bot to flask to create a URL for discord.
when I run it, it doesn't do it. Am I missing a line here because it is not coming up with an error but it will not run either.

````
from threading import Thread

app = Flask ('__code__')

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "Hello. I am alive!"
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)


def keep_alive():
          t = Thread(target=run)
          t.start()

if __name__ == '__code__':
  app.run()```

Can someone point me in the right direction? I normally work on python 3. 

Thank you
````

Comment: Can you provide more information about the issue that you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app when checking the name of your code, not in `home()` function:

```
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

app = Flask ('__code__')

@app.route('/')
def home():
  return "Hello. I am alive!"

def keep_alive():
          t = Thread(target=run)
          t.start()

if __name__ == '__code__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```